# Are there any publicly available mailing list/consumer address services or databases out there?

Tags: azure, dataset, mailing-list, azure-marketplace

I've got a requirement to turn some partial person contact information into potential mailing addresses (the evils of marketing: given firstname, lastname, zip find addresses in that area that are likely that person).

Short of contracting a third party mailing list data vendor are there any publicly available datasets or services that I could explore?

I've looked on the [azure data marketplace](https://datamarket.azure.com/) and don't see anything. And my google skills are failing me.

Answer (score 2):

[StrikeIron](http://www.strikeiron.com/Home.aspx) has a [US Address Verification](http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/4c0a5ee7-2e32-459a-a0bb-80a6e3c6cae0) feed on DataMarket that might work for you.